# GEF: How to pass selections to a Command

Tags: graph, command, selection, eclipse-gef

I have a GEF Editor with a Command to create a new node. I want to pass the current selection of nodes in the editor to this command, in order to let the command create a new node **and** create connections from the new node to the selected nodes in the editor.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the edit policy you can call `getHost().getViewer().getSelectedEditParts()` to get the selected edit parts, and then pass their model to the `Command` used to create the new node.

IMO, instead of one single command to do this you should have different commands for node creation and link creation and create a compound command in your edit policy that first creates the node and then creates the link. This gives you better modularity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks also for the tip with the compund commands! Great tip!